# Django. How to send 'fake' MIME type Image to avoid warning

Tags: django

I send a quick message to my server by setting the message as an image src. (It's faster than Ajax and I don't need a response).

```
var img = new Image();
var msg= "something happened";
img.src = my_domain_url +'?' + msg;
```

Server side I return something to avoid an error:

```
return HttpResponse("ok")
```

However, I get a warning:

"Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:"

How can I avoid that? I guess I need to send an image type, but do I need to send an actual image?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain why creating this image hack is faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course you're going to get that message, you're telling JavaScript to get an Image at some URL but instead text is being returned.  You could just do

```
HttpResponse("ok", content_type="image/jpeg")
```

Though i'm not sure what the implications are of returning the string "ok" to a `var image` in JavaScript.

see the documentation on the [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse)